# Disable or Skip address collection for USD in stripe session Checkout API

Tags: python, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am integration a stripe session checkout API.

```
    line_items=[
        {
            "price_data": {
                "currency": "usd",
                "product_data": {
                    "name": "order - 1234",
                },
                "unit_amount_decimal": 100,
            },
            "quantity": 1,
        },
    ],
    customer_email="john@doe.com",
    mode="payment",
    success_url="succes_url",
    cancel_url="cancel_url",
)
```

here is my stripe code to create a session for USD but when I open URL than it Ask for address details how can I skip or disable it.

i have tried on google but not getting proper solutions for it
[image: Image is attached FYR]

Comment: How is your billing_address_collection on that Checkout Session?
It is documented here, either "auto" or "required", and it is defaulted to "auto" which only collect Billing Address when necessary:  https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-billing_address_collection

If it's "auto" already, then there is no way to further disable it.